# PopupMenuButton has click layer, how to remove?

Tags: flutter

At the moment for drop-downs we are using PopupMenuButton.

But the problem is, is that it adds a click layer over it, that intercepts the click-layer underneath and shows a grey hover box. Does anyone know an alternative / fix for this?

There doesn't seem to be any theme or property to remove it :-|

As you can see below, there is a grey click area..
[image]

```
  _notificationBell(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(),
      child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
        // Callback that sets the selected popup menu item.
        onSelected: (String item) {},
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/bell.svg",
              semanticsLabel: 'Bell icon',
              width: 26,
              height: 26,
              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
            ),
            if (userProviderWatch(context).numberOfUnreadBellNotifications() != 0)
              Positioned(
                left: 3,
                top: 3,
                child: Container(
                  width: 8,
                  height: 8,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        enableFeedback: false,
        tooltip: lang.bellNotificationsTitle,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
            enabled: true,
            value: "ttt",
            child: ModalBellNotifications(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the item and it shouldnt close the menu items, Can you describe a little more what will be behavior on click event or an ui

Comment: Trying to remove the click overlay from PopupMenuItem